# Unable to print integer array

Tags: c

Im a newbie to C, I primarily migrated/re-implemeted C programs to Java, etc. I'm trying to learn C and I have gone through several tutorials. I have a program that attempts to read user input(numbers) from command line via `char *argv`, sort those numbers and just print the sorted numbers out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        //if the is argument supplied
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            int count = 0;
            //array to sort less 1
            count = argc -1;
            int tobe_sorted[count];
            int i=0;
            //allocate memory for target result array
            int *target = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
            //copy unsorted ints to target
            memcpy(target, tobe_sorted, count * sizeof(int));
            //sort target using bubble sort
            int temp =0;
            int x =0;
            int y=0;
            for (x=0; x<count; x++ )
            {
                for (y=0; y<count -1; y++ )
                {
                    if (target[i]>target[i+1])
                    {
                        temp = target[i+1];
                        target[i+1] = target[i];
                        target[i] = temp;

                    }
                }//end inner

            }//end outer

            //end bubble sort
            x=0;
            printf("Sorted:\n");
            //print sorted array
            while (x <count)
            {
                printf("%d",target[x]);
                printf(",");
                x++;
            }
             printf("\n");
        }//end argument supplied
        else{
            printf("Error, please enter numbers to be sorted\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }//end main function
```

### My input

```
PS C:\Users\xyz\workspace_cpp\the_hard_way\ex18> .\sort_test.exe 5 4 3 2 1
```

### Output

```
Sorted:
2686748 1986196690 32 1 4199492
```

1. I'm not sure what C is printing out, are these ASCII codes?
2. What do I need to fix in the above program in order to print the sorted int array?

*Disclaimer: Im not looking to use library functions such as qsort(), or to make the program more efficient.*

Edited & working code based on comments (there is an extra index being allocated in target array, otherwise sorting & char to int conversion is working):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        //if thee is argument supplied
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            int count = 0;
            count = argc;
            int tobe_sorted[count-1];
            //initialize with 0's
            int i=0;
            for (;i<count; i++)
            {
                tobe_sorted[i] = 0;
            }
            //populate tobe_sorted with integer values of argv
            i=0;
            for (;i<count; i++)
            {
                tobe_sorted[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
            }

            //allocate memory for target result array
            int *target = malloc((count * sizeof(int)));
            //copy unsorted ints to target
            memcpy(target, tobe_sorted, count * sizeof(int));
            //sort target using bubble sort
            int tmp =0;
            int x =0;
            int y=0;
            int swapped = 1; 
            while (swapped)
            {
                swapped =0; 
                y++;
                for (x=0; x < count - y; x++)
                {
                    if (target[x] > target[x+1])
                    {
                        tmp = target[x];
                        target[x] = target[x+1];
                        target[x+1] = tmp;
                        swapped = 1; 
                    }
                }
            }
            //end bubble sort
            x=0;
            printf("Sorted:\n");
            //print sorted array
            while (x <count)
            {
                printf("%d",target[x]);
                printf(",");
                x++;
            }
             printf("\n");
        }//end argument supplied
        else{
            printf("Error, please enter numbers to be sorted\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }//end main function
```

**Input:**

PS C:\Users\xyz\workspace_cpp\the_hard_way\ex18> .\sort_test.exe 5 -3 -2 1 8

**Output**
Sorted:
-3,-2,0,1,5,8,

Comment: First thing is to decide if you're trying to learn C or C++, and get your tags right.

Comment: `memcpy(target, tobe_sorted, count * sizeof(int));` looks wrong. `tobe_sorted` is uninitialized. Did you mean to use `argv`? Even if so, that would still be wrong. The `argv` values are strings not integers. You need to convert each argv string to an int with `atoi` or `strtol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `target` or `tobe_sorted` - they are "full of junk".

You never take the numbers off your command line `argv` and do anything with them.

You're going to need to convert the strings in `argv` into `ints`. Something like this:

```
for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    tobe_sorted[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
}
```

Before your `memcpy()`

Comment: Sorry for horrible(idiotic) post , I was actually in a hurry , yes you & all other are all right, I fixed the issue & edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you are not using `argv` at all.

You declare an array named `tobe_sorted`, you don't initialize its values (so it contains garbage).

Then you copy the data on the `target` array and you sort that garbage data. Then you print them.

You must parse `argv`, convert each argument to an `int` using something like [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) and then sort these values.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

1. `int tobe_sorted[count];`

This is uninitialized.  It currently contains junk.  You're then copying that junk to your target array.

2. `//copy unsorted ints to target
    memcpy(target, tobe_sorted, count * sizeof(int));`

As mentioned in 1, your `tobe_sorted` array doesn't contain your data.  You want to parse `*argv[]`, which is an array of arrays that contains the actual cmdline input.  `argc` just tells you how many elements exist in `*argv[]` array.
You need to parse the `argv` array, convert each element into an `int` and store the results in the `tobe_sorted` array.